# OpenGL glShaderSource throws an exception

Tags: c++, opengl, exception

This code throws nvoglv32.dll exception. I think there is an error in glShaderSource somewherer, but I can't find it

```
ifstream ifs("vertexShader.txt");
string vertexShadersSource((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

ifs.close();
ifs.open("fragmentShader.txt");
string fragmentShadersSource((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

cout << fragmentShadersSource.c_str() << endl;
cout << vertexShadersSource.c_str() << endl;

GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint fragmentShader, vertexShader;
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

const char *data = vertexShadersSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &data, (GLint*)vertexShadersSource.size());
data = fragmentShadersSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &data, (GLint*)fragmentShadersSource.size());
```

**EDIT:**

Although I think the shader is correct, here you can see the shader code
VertexShader:

```
#version 150
// in_Position was bound to attribute index 0 and in_Color was bound to       attribute index 1
//in  vec2 in_Position;
//in  vec3 in_Color;

// We output the ex_Color variable to the next shader in the chain
out vec3 ex_Color;
void main(void) {
// Since we are using flat lines, our input only had two points: x and y.
// Set the Z coordinate to 0 and W coordinate to 1

//gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x, in_Position.y, 0.0, 1.0);

// GLSL allows shorthand use of vectors too, the following is also valid:
// gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 0.0, 1.0);
// We're simply passing the color through unmodified

ex_Color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

FragmentShader:

```
#version 150
// It was expressed that some drivers required this next line to function   properly
precision highp float;

in  vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main(void) {
// Pass through our original color with full opacity.
gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);
}
```

Comment: How do you create OpenGL context? What is the content of `vertexShader.txt` and `fragmentShader.txt`?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I use glfw to create my window and I use glfwMakeContextCurrent(window) to create the context.

Comment: genpfault is right. We'll need to see more code to be able to help you. Anyway, did you call `glfwInit()` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call is wrong:

> ```
> glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &data, (GLint*)vertexShadersSource.size());
> ```

and the type cast from a `size_t` to a pointer type should have raised some red flags while you wrote it.

[glShaderSource()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) expects a pointer *to an array of string lenghts* - one element per separate string. Since you only use 1 string, it will try to access `lenght[0]`. This means it treats your string size as an address, and that address is very likely to not belong to your process.

Since you already use 0-terminated C-Strings, you can simply use `NULL` as the `length` parameter. Or, if you absolutely want to use it, you have to just pass a pointer to an GLint:

```
GLint len=vertexShadersSource.size();
glShaderSource(..., 1, ..., &len);
```